# MySQL JOIN and WHERE construct

Tags: mysql

it is probably trivial. I use JOIN to get the results from "brewary" and "type" tables but it does not return any results.
In "type" table I have only `Druh_ID` column `(ID number)` and text column related to it `(1 => 'Pivo')`.
If I use the "Druh_ID" in the last row `(WHERE type.Druh_ID IN ('1'))` then it works but not with the other column.

```
SELECT  brewary.Znacka, type.Druh
FROM brewary
JOIN type ON type.Druh_ID=brewary.Druh_ID
WHERE type.Druh IN ('Pivo')
```

Comment: Could you provide some more detail on your tables? As in, how you define them? It sounds like you defined one with a non-integer key, although I am not positive. 

Even better, you could create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some sample data. It would greatly help us to help you!

Comment: Thank you Brandon. Yes, i defined the "Druh" column as VARCHAR, NOT NULL. I checked and if I use SELECT type.Druh FROM type WHERE type.Druh NOT IN ('Pivo') then it returns everything even the string 'Pivo'... So the issue has to be that it does not match the 'PIVO' in the "WHERE IN" function with the text in the Database column.

Comment: Hi, i just found out that it all works if I insert the data into the "type" table using the regular "INSERT INTO table" construct. But as I uploaded the data into the database from a text file it does not work. Would you know what could be the issue?  LOAD DATA INFILE "Druh.txt" INTO TABLE type
CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"

Comment: I just found the issue. When I used the "LOAD DATA INFILE" construct, there was added automatically a space and 'enter' behind the fields in second column even when the txt file did not include it.